# React Native app and importing native Android module

Tags: android, ios, react-native, sdk

Since I did not get any answers from the previous post, I am posting again.
I have many experiences in Android native development but am a beginner in React Native. Wish to build a React Native app but need to find out these answers before I can start making architecture:

Is it possible to import a native Android module/ SDK (which is programmed in Java/ Kotlin) into React Native app? (I believe it is yes as I saw many good articles on the internet)

If I import the native Android module/ SDK to React Native app, does the app runs on iOS devices as well? Able to use APIs which native Android module/ SDK supports? (Or do I need a native iOS module/ SDK for iOS itself?)

I think this is similar to question #2. After importing the native Android module, does it also run on the web without a problem?

Looking forward to getting answers.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to integrate [Android Native Modules](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android#register-the-module-android-specific).

No app doesn't run on iOS device if you have only Android SDK, You need to have a native iOS module to integrate [iOS Native Modules](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios#export-a-native-method-to-javascript).

For Web, I don't think so since both are native modules.

For more, please ref : [native-modules-intro](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-intro)